# (C#) WaitForDebugEvent fails without an exception or reason

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, winapi, memory

Hello fellow engineers.

I am writing an anti-debugger that attempts to protect a process that was created through process hollowing. My process is created with CreateProcess and the process creation flag I pass is 0x00000004 (CREATE_SUSPENDED). I manually map the PE's sections and headers in memory and allocate the necessary memory, before I run ResumeThread() however, I start a new thread that runs an anti-debugger on the process using WinAPI's debugging methods.

The code that does the anti-debugging is the following:

```
    public void StartProtection(Win32Api.ProcessInformation processInfo, int sizeOfHeaders, int imageBase)
    {
        Win32Api.DEBUG_EVENT debugEvent = default(Win32Api.DEBUG_EVENT);

        int processId = Win32Api.GetProcessId(processInfo.ProcessHandle);
        if (processId == 0) return;

        if (!Win32Api.DebugActiveProcess(processId))
            return;

        Win32Api.DebugSetProcessKillOnExit(true);

        int oldProtection = 0;
        bool flag = true;
        while (flag)
        {
            if (Win32Api.WaitForDebugEvent(ref debugEvent, -1))
            {
                switch (debugEvent.dwDebugEventCode - (Win32Api.DebugEventType)1)
                {
                    case 0:
                        if (debugEvent.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode == 0x80000001)
                        {
                            Win32Api.ContinueDebugEvent(processId, (int)processInfo.ThreadId, 65538);
                            if (!VirtualProtectEx(processInfo.ProcessHandle, imageBase, sizeOfHeaders, 320,
                                ref oldProtection))
                                return;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if (VirtualProtectEx(processInfo.ProcessHandle, imageBase, sizeOfHeaders, 320,
                            ref oldProtection))
                        {
                            Api.ResumeThread(processInfo.ThreadHandle);
                            CloseHandle(debugEvent.LoadDll.hFile);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        flag = false;
                        Win32Api.DebugActiveProcessStop(processId);
                        break;

                }
                Win32Api.ContinueDebugEvent(processId, (int)processInfo.ThreadId, 65538);
            }
        }
    }
```

While step-by-step debugging, when I enter the following line, it will proceed a few times before unexpectedly stopping right there:

```
if (Win32Api.WaitForDebugEvent(ref debugEvent, -1))
```

I call the anti-debugger thread like this:

```
                ThreadStart threadStart = ctx.RunAntiDebugger;
                Thread thread = new Thread(threadStart) { IsBackground = true };
                thread.Start();
                thread.Join();
```

(RunAntiDebugger is just a wrapper function calls the StartProtection function above with the right parameters)

The line following the above thread initiating code is this:

```
            if (Api.ResumeThread(ctx.ProcessInformation.ThreadHandle) == -1)
                return false;
```

If I remove the thread.Join(); call, the hollowed process runs properly but the anti-debugger doesn't seem to prevent any debugger. However, if I join the thread, the anti-debugging works and the debug messages are handled properly but the process never runs in the end (stays suspended for ever).

Any ideas what might be causing this? I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of days but my efforts were fruitless so far. Any input will be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just to get the obvious stuff out of the way: you're calling ContinueDebugEvent() twice for the same event in the case of a guard page exception.  Also, if that's really your code, the error handling is inadequate.  You need to raise an exception or log an error or *something* when an API call fails, not just ignore it.  As-is, there's pretty much no hope of figuring out what's going wrong.  It also seems a little odd that you're resuming the target process main thread twice?

Comment: @HarryJohnston ResumeThread will return -1 if the thread is already resumed. I am including this line in case it never enters the case 2 switch label. The problem is, I get no errors back with it. 

`Win32Api.WaitForDebugEvent(ref debugEvent, -1)` seems to be the line causing the problems (I've figured it out as I've logged errors but removed the code that does so because whether this code runs or not is not the problem. The problem is the line I mentioned earlier. When it fails, it doesn't return false. It just stops there for some reason.

Comment: use `CREATE_SUSPENDED` and call `Win32Api.DebugActiveProcess` error in your case. you need create process with `DEBUG_PROCESS` flag instead. first of all change this

Comment: of course calling ContinueDebugEvent() twice is error, you not handle initial `STATUS_BREAKPOINT`.. but begin from my first comment - use `DEBUG_PROCESS`. not use `CREATE_SUSPENDED` and call `Win32Api.DebugActiveProcess` - this main your error from which all begin

Comment: It is perfectly normal for `WaitForDebugEvent` to block - the word "Wait" does appear in the name of the function, after all!  The only question is why you're not getting any more events.  Start by fixing the double-continue bug and trying RbMm's suggestion.  But of course process hollowing is unsupported, so it is entirely possible that debugging just won't work in your scenario.  (I'm not saying that it won't, just that it is possible.)

Comment: also handle `CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT`, `LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT` is mandatary - nobode close handles for you. and begin from exec and debug simply process - say notepad. without suspen/resume/virtualprotect/etc. only after you can be absle trace it from `CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT` to `EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT` begin your task